# How to manage that iframe was loaded when given url return 204

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe

I saw the response given here:

[How to rightly detect iframe was loaded with response 204 No Content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869737/how-to-rightly-detect-iframe-was-loaded-with-response-204-no-content)

but it didn't help.

It is possible, to check (using events, not checking a content of an iframe), that iframe was loaded (request was send)?

Example:

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-frcf1k?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: do you have access to the code of the webapp within the iframe?

Comment: I need to make an assumption that I will not have access to the code of page under given url

Comment: This isn't really an angular question. Javascript in general can't really handle proper error detection on iframes.

Comment: @EliezerBerlin So, do you know how to handle this situation?

Comment: @AleksanderBurzec Sorry. I asked Google, but he was pretty unhelpful. But if you come up with a JS solution, I'd be happy to help translate it into Angular, no problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect the load event of an `iframe`, but not the status of `204` unless you use a `fetch` or `xmlhttprequest`. This still cannot be perfect because that website's `httpheader` may allow for it be embedded in `iframes` but not `fetched`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use iframe `onLoad` event and can detect if the iframe has been loaded.

Example:

```html
 <iframe src="https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page" onLoad="(() => console.log('Loaded'))()" />
```

Comment: onLoad is not triggerred when page returns 204 (No content) - see stackblitz example

Comment: You could use ajax request to check if the iframe url has 204 status code or not.

Answer (score -1):

this is what i managed to do.
i grabbed the iframe element with ElementRef.

html:

```
<iframe #iframe name="blah" id="blah" src="https://httpstat.us/204"></iframe>
```

ts:

```
@ViewChild("iframe") iframe: ElementRef;
```

end AfterViewInit i am checking if the src string ends with '204'.

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const src = this.iframe.nativeElement.getAttribute("src");
    if (src.endsWith("204")) {
      console.log("iframe loading failed");
    } else {
      console.log("iframe load succesfuly");
    }
  }
```

see here:
[stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jszqva)

Comment: This is an example url, which returns 204. In real scenario that can be "https://httpstat.us/blah" or "https://httpstat.us/otherOne" and  this is really funny solution

Comment: You can modify it to check if it doesn't match the expected src on a successful load. Can't you?

Comment: This is not a root of a problem. Checking url pattern is not a solution

Comment: What kind of solution are you expecting?

Comment: I want to know, that iframe was loaded, when given page returns http status "No Content". Standard event handlers are not triggered.